# parity bit question

Tags: networking

i have been readin about the "parity bit" method, and how is is used to check is the "packet" is received correctly.

so using odd parity: (from wiki)

```
A wants to transmit:          1001
A computes parity bit value:  ~(1^0^0^1) = 1
A adds parity bit and sends:  10011
B receives:                   10011
B computes overall parity:    1^0^0^1^1 = 1
B reports correct transmission after observing expected odd result.
```

what if during the transmission, instead of "10011", 
"11001" is received. how will the parity check for that, since it checks only the number of "1"'s ?
or is it impossible for bits to change during transmission like i stated before? thx

Comment: it doesn't. you need higher order checks for those circumstances: CRC, Hamming....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parity bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit) is simplest [error detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction) technique. It works if odd number of bits (including the parity bit) are transmitted incorrectly. So if two bits are corrupt then it will not work.